# Complex Excel VBA - Trying to use specific online calculator and download data to excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel VBA and would appreciate if someone can help me to find the solution to the problem.  I have an excel sheet with some specific values, and I would like excel to open the website, select the appropriate calculator and enter the values and save the output to excel.

With various online tutorials, I am able to  achieve the following

1: Open the website 
2: Select the appropriate calculator

But after that, I am not able to get my code to work. I have spent few hours looking for an online solution but no help. I would appreciate if someone can help me.

Please teach me how can I get my code to do the following

1: Do the calculation for all the values in my excel sheet
2: Copy the total amount to the excel sheet.

I have attached my excel file and the code.

Excel File Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/96mz24a9sho4b2l/MACROEABLED.xlsm?dl=0

Thank you.

```
  Sub automaticformfilling()

Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://cf.oeb.ca/html/_calculator/BillCalc.cfm"
    'Wait for loading
     Do While .busy
     DoEvents
Loop

Do While .readystate <> 4
DoEvents
```

Loop

```
End With
```

Set district = ie.document.getelementbyid("ddCompanies")

```
For i = 1 To district.Options.Length
If district.Options(i).Text = "ENWIN Utilities Ltd." Then
    district.selectedindex = i
    Exit For
End If
```

Next i

```
ie.document.getelementbyid("ddCompanies").fireevent ("onchange")

Set variableusage = ie.document.getelementbyid("txtEnterUsage")
SendKeys ("{BACKSPACE}")
 enter code here   End Sub
```

Comment: So you select a specified utility company then are you inputting values from your excel sheet into the calculator and wanting to retrieve the results?

Comment: @QHarr Yes, that's what I would like to do.

Comment: much easier with the Google Sheets `=IMPORTXML(url, "//tr[@class='total']/td[2]")`, if that's an option https://www.geckoboard.com/blog/part-1-6-google-sheets-functions-you-probably-dont-know-but-should/, and example url is https://cf.oeb.ca/html/_calculator/BillCalc.cfm?dist=ENWIN+Utilities+Ltd.+%3A+Main&var_Usage=750&RPPorTOU=rbTOU&txtOffPeak=65&txtMidPeak=17&txtOnPeak=18&OESPcredit=0&txtContractPrice=0&btnCalculateRetail=Calculate

Comment: @Slai That looks interesting. How does one enter the required company and values though?

Comment: @Slai - Thank you for your comment. I am not familiar with google docs but it looks like that this solution might work. I would just like to know how can i use the google doc to select different values for "total kWh"

Comment: they are parameters in the example url in my comment `dist=` (needs to be url encoded), and `var_Usage=750`. There are also some similar VBA alternatives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165276/function-similar-to-importxml-in-excel

Comment: @slai Ok. So you could construct an URL string in a loop picking up the parameters from the sheet and sending a request out and parsing the response? And construct a function to parse the response for ease of use.

Comment: or just generate the url in formula or UDF ..

Comment: @Slai - I am able to construct the formula in google docs but how can program this formula to pick var_usage value from a column in my google docs sheet?

Comment: @Slai What do you mean by dist= (needs to be url encoded) ? Can you point me to an examples? I can see that it is has changed from simply the selected utility name.

Comment: @QHarr seems like `IMPORTXML` is taking care of that. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: @Slai Thanks for your patience :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked. Thanks to @Slai for the comments that lead to this.

**TODO:**

1. Review validity of the optional arguments to function
2. Rename faux hungarian style variables to something else

**References:**

1. Microsoft XML, v6.0 'this will vary with your Excel version
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public counter As Long

Public Sub ExtractBillInfo()

    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60 'This will vary according to your Excel version
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim utility As String
    Dim var_usage As Double
    Dim RPPorTOU As String
    Dim OESPcredit As Double
    Dim txtContractPrice As Double
    Dim txtOffPeak As Double
    Dim txtMidPeak As Double
    Dim txtOnPeak As Double

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7") 'change as appropriate
        utility = .Range("B1")
        var_usage = .Range("B2")
        RPPorTOU = .Range("B3")
        OESPcredit = .Range("B4")
        txtContractPrice = .Range("B5")
        txtOffPeak = .Range("B6")
        txtMidPeak = .Range("B7")
        txtOnPeak = .Range("B8")
    End With

    With http

        .Open "GET", ConstructURL(utility, var_usage, RPPorTOU, OESPcredit, txtContractPrice, txtOffPeak, txtMidPeak, txtOnPeak), False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim elemCol As IHTMLElementCollection
    Set elemCol = html.getElementsByClassName("bill")

    Dim t As IHTMLTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8") ''change as appropriate
   ' ws.Cells.ClearContents
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = utility

    For Each t In elemCol

        PrintTable ws, t

    Next t

End Sub

Public Function ConstructURL(ByVal utility As String, ByVal var_usage As Double, ByVal RPPorTOU As String, _
                             ByVal OESPcredit As Double, ByVal txtContractPrice As Double, Optional ByVal txtOffPeak As Double = 0, Optional ByVal txtMidPeak As Double = 0, Optional ByVal txtOnPeak As Double = 0)

    ConstructURL = "https://cf.oeb.ca/html/_calculator/BillCalc.cfm?dist=" & Join(Split(utility, Chr(32)), "+") & _
                    "+%3A+Main&var_Usage=" & var_usage & _
                    "&RPPorTOU=" & RPPorTOU & _
                    "&txtOffPeak=" & txtOffPeak & _
                    "&txtMidPeak=" & txtMidPeak & _
                    "&txtOnPeak=" & txtOnPeak & _
                    "&OESPcredit=" & OESPcredit & _
                    "&txtContractPrice=" & txtContractPrice & _
                    "&btnCalculateRetail=Calculate"
Debug.Print ConstructURL
End Function

Public Sub PrintTable(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal t As IHTMLTable)

    Dim r As Long, c As Long, counter As Long

    Dim curHTMLRow As Object

    For r = 1 To t.Rows.Length - 1

        counter = counter + 1
        Set curHTMLRow = t.Rows(r)

        With ws

            For c = 0 To curHTMLRow.Cells.Length - 1
                .Cells(counter + 1, c + 1) = curHTMLRow.Cells(c).innerText
            Next c

        End With

    Next r

End Sub
```

**Test cases:**

1. Burlington Hydro Inc
2. Attawapiskat Power Corp
3. ENWIN Utilities Ltd
4. Centre Wellington Hydro Ltd

**Sample variables:**

Data in A1:B8 Sheet 7 . Result output goes into Sheet8

```
| utility          | Centre Wellington Hydro Ltd |
|------------------|-----------------------------|
| var_usage        | 100                         |
| RPPorTOU         | rbTOU                       |
| txtOffPeak       | 0                           |
| txtMidPeak       | 17                          |
| txtOnPeak        | 18                          |
| OESPcredit       | 20                          |
| txtContractPrice | 2                           |
```

**In sheet:**

[image: Data]

**Notes:**

1. `utility`  and  `RPPorTOU`  are data validation lists in my sheet. `utility` allows you to pick company and `RPPorTOU` allows either rbRPP | rbTOU
2. I got the company names to use (and some have white additional white space) by pulling from the option values listed in the [view source](http://view-source:https://cf.oeb.ca/html/_calculator/BillCalc.cfm).

**Some example outputs:**

[image: Outputs]

Comment: Was this of any use?

Comment: Thank you soo much QHarr - This worked perfectly for me. The importxml formula also worked perfectly but it was taking really long to load the values.  This one solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets, the formula could be :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://cf.oeb.ca/html/_calculator/BillCalc.cfm?dist=" & 
  "ENWIN Utilities Ltd. : Main" & "&var_Usage=" & 750 &
  "&RPPorTOU=rbTOU&txtOffPeak=65&txtMidPeak=17&txtOnPeak=18&OESPcredit=0" & 
  "&txtContractPrice=0&btnCalculateRetail=Calculate", "//tr[@class='total']/td[2]")
```

where the `"ENWIN Utilities Ltd. : Main"` and `750` parts can come from cells.

The company values can be found in the page HTML:

```
<option value="ENWIN Utilities Ltd. : Main">ENWIN Utilities Ltd.</option>
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The URL parameters can be found in Google Chrome DevTools > Network tab > click Calculate button on page > click BillCalc.cfm in Network tab > Headers > Form Data > view source

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Impressed!

Comment: Hi Slai - Sorry to bother you again. I tried Google Chrome DevTools > Network > Headers > Form Data > view source but I am still not able to find the URL.

Comment: @HasenCH I skipped some steps .. see if the update helps

Comment: Yes, after the update I was able to get the URL. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Slai - The formula worked earlier perfectly but when I increase the number of records then I get the loading error on all cells. How can i fix this issue in google docs?

Comment: @HasenCH You can try less records at a time. If your IP address is blocked from generating too much traffic, you can try different machine.